# MomentJS parsing date works with two dates but shows 'Invalid Date' for the third

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, date, momentjs

I have already tried out at least 50 solutions from posts here in SO but nothing seems to be working. I have three dates:

```
Date 1: 2018-10-28T17:21:38Z
Date 2: 2020-10-28T22:29:30Z
Date 3: 2021-10-28T17:21:38Z
```

Trying to parse it to something readable. Date 1 and Date 2 works perfectly but Date 3 shows `Invalid Date`.

```
Date 1: Sun Oct 28 2018 23:21:38 GMT+0600
Date 2: Thu Oct 29 2020 04:29:30 GMT+0600
Date 3: Invalid Date
```

Also throws a deprecation warning in the terminal:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 2021-10-28T17:21:38Z , _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
```

This is the code:

```js
const date1 = moment('2018-10-28T17:21:38Z').toString();
console.log(date1);

const date2 = moment('2020-10-28T22:29:30Z').toString(); 
console.log(date2);

const date3 = moment('2021-10-28T17:21:38Z').toString();
console.log(date3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Is this happening because Date 3 is a future date? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Weird. I just tried it in a JSFiddle, and it's working for me.

Comment: Also works for me in JSFiddle, Moment 2.2.1 http://jsfiddle.net/0w1synqe/

Comment: can't reproduce it either in JSFiddle, with moment 2.29.1, what version of moment are you using?

Comment: Guys I'm using 2.29.1 and it doesn't work. How does it work for you guys but not me? :(

Comment: your snippet is working

Comment: @Nonik it seems to be working here but not in my Nodejs Express app. Weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

work for me too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Test Moment</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Moment Test" />
    <meta name="author" content="Test" />
  </head>

  <body>
    Hi
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const date1 = moment("2018-10-28T17:21:38Z").toString(); // Sun Oct 28 2018 20:51:38 GMT+0330
      console.log(date1);

      const date2 = moment("2020-10-28T22:29:30Z").toString(); // Thu Oct 29 2020 01:59:30 GMT+0330
      console.log(date2);

      const date3 = moment("2021-10-28T17:21:38Z").toString(); // Thu Oct 28 2021 20:51:38 GMT+0330
      console.log(date3);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

update your moment module or you need to put the format in the moment constructor...

```
const moment = require('moment');
let oldDate = "2021-10-28T17:21:38Z";
let newDate = moment(oldDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
let strNewDate = moment(oldDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").toString()
console.log(newDate)
console.log(strNewDate )
```